# Spring RestTemplate for Microservices - Passing object in POST

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, microservices, resttemplate

I've been trying to communicate with two spring-microservices via restTemplate.
If I use GET, it works fine. Below is the controller with GET:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/empCenter")
public ModelAndView welcome(@RequestParam("username")String username, @RequestParam List<String> authorities, HttpServletRequest request) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("welcome");

    return modelAndView;
}
```

And this is how I called restTemplate for the above endpoint:

```
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder
            .fromHttpUrl("http://Bismillah-employee-service/empCenter")
            .queryParam("username",  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName())
            .queryParam("authorities", SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities().toArray());
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("username",  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());

    return restTemplate.getForEntity(builder.toUriString(), String.class).getBody();
```

Now the issue is: if I would like to pass an Object to the restTemplate - I need to pass it as **RequestBody**; thus my endpoint has to be for POST. Therefore, I tried as below:

```
    @PostMapping(value="/empCenter", consumes = "application/json")
    public ModelAndView welcome(@RequestBody Authentication authentication, HttpServletRequest request) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("welcome");
    //modelAndView.addObject("authorities", authorities);

    return modelAndView;
}
```

And below is how I called above controller:

```
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    headers.add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36");
    HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity<>(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(), headers);
    String response =  restTemplate.postForEntity("http://Bismillah-employee-service/empCenter",
            entity,
            String.class).getBody();
```

Even though, at this point, my user is already authenticated and logged-in (from login page); I'm getting following error:
**stacktrace**

```
    2019-09-15 22:35:02.874 DEBUG 12744 --- [nio-8762-exec-2] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 403 FORBIDDEN
2019-09-15 22:38:39.378  INFO 12744 --- [trap-executor-0] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2019-09-15 22:40:16.122 DEBUG 12744 --- [nio-8762-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 null
2019-09-15 22:40:16.122 DEBUG 12744 --- [nio-8762-exec-2] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@22e8e446
2019-09-15 22:40:16.122 DEBUG 12744 --- [nio-8762-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2019-09-15 22:40:16.124 ERROR 12744 --- [nio-8762-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 null] with root cause

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 null
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:83) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:122) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:778) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:736) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:445) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sam.bismillahGateway.controller.WelcomeRestController.openEmployeeCenterApp(WelcomeRestController.java:64) ~[classes/:na]
```

Can you guys shed some lights?
Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
Here's is the security config as requested:

***Security config for login-microservice( from where I call the Employee-microservice)***

```
    @Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.
            jdbcAuthentication()
            .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login","/registration").permitAll() 
            //.antMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            //.defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome")
            .successHandler(successHandler)
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and().logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/403");

}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
}
```

***Security config for Employee-microservice:***

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.
            authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll();
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
}
```

Comment: Please share your spring security configuration.

Comment: @chaoluo, I've updated with the security config. BTW, I'm using eureka server for service-discovery. Just wondering, do I need to do anything special for POST request in order to authenticate the microservice?
***o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 401 UNAUTHORIZED***